# How to exclude results in graphql query

Tags: sdl-tridion, sites-9.5, graphql, query

I want to find a page through its keywords and/or metadata.

I have this query that works correctly and returns all the pages with the keyword **9999** and **aValue**.

```
{
  items(filter: {
    namespaceIds: [1],
    publicationIds: [9],
    itemTypes: [PAGE], 
    keyword: { categoryId: 99, keywordId: 9999 },
    customMeta: { key: "aKey", value: "aValue" }
}) {
  // ...
}
```

But I get more than one page. Is there a way to deny keywords or metadata values like as?

```
isNull: { keyword: { categoryId: 100 } }
```

or

```
notExists: { keyword: { categoryId: 100, keyword: 10000 } }
```

or

```
not: { customMeta: { key: 'anotherKey' } }
```

or

```
customMeta: { key: 'anotherKey', value: null }
```

Thanks a lot